# Is Hash(bG) equal to b(Hash(G))?

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography, hash-function

Assume b  is an integer, G  is a basepoint in an elliptic curve, and Hash  is a one-way hash function.

Is Hash(bG)  equal to b(Hash(G)) ? or not?

Note: A hash function is any algorithm or subroutine that maps data sets of variable length to data sets of a fixed length. For example, a person's name, having a variable length, could be hashed to a single integer of bounded size. The values returned by a hash function are called hash values, hash codes, hash sums, checksums or simply hashes. in this example hash function is a funcion that convert a point on elliptic curve that is Input of hash function, to an integer number, that is output of hash function.

Comment: Is onewayness the only security property you assume? I.e., given $h(x)=y$ it should be hard to find $x$. Other properties include, second preimage resistance: given $x$ find $x'\neq x$ s.t. $h(x)=h(x')$, collision resistance: find $x,y$ with $x\neq y$ s.t. $h(x)=h(y)$.

Comment: you're right, but in this example our concern is not Hash functions and their properties. I know Hash function properties. I don't know answer of this question. instead of hash function you assume a function exist that convert a point on elliptic curve to a integer number.

Comment: Well, let $Hash(X)=0$ for all $X$. Then $Hash(bG)=0=b(Hash(G))$. This is too simple though, so I'm assuming $Hash$ must have other properties that you have not stated.

Comment: no, think about other situations. hash(x)<>0. hash(x)= any integer number. you're right, with respect to your perspective hash function have other properties.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Is it, in general,for all functions $Hash$ does the property hold, or is it, does there exist such a function? If the former, no, if the latter, yes (as shown my my comment).

Comment: thank you, my question is in general not with a specefic hash function.

Comment: Can you help me about http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417320/solving-equation-related-to-an-elliptic-curve